# Is azure website support using WSA (winsock)

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, dll

I am developing an MVC Web app on Azure website. My service call to a unmanaged DLL that uses the Winsock to communicate with alarm system. I know that Azure website supports WebSockets so I wondering if it supports the Winsock too?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking if you can allow traffic on specific TCP/IP ports to/from the Azure Website, and the answer is no.

You can still achieve what you want using a Cloud Service instead of WebSite (**WebRole**), which basically gives you more options, i.e. the ability to allow specific ports.

Reference here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-configure-roles-for-cloud-service/#manage-endpoints-and-certificates-for-your-roles

Comment: but i succedd to use tcpclient class on azure website, so how this is work?  TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

tcpclnt.Connect("server_name", port_number);
                             
tcpclnt.Close();